# Получение сообщений Telegram Api [Решено]

Tags: telegram

Пытаюсь получить имеющиеся сообщения (входящие и исходящие) по всем чатам используя MadelineProto.
Нашел только метод getHistory (https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/messages.getHistory.html)

```
$messages = $MadelineProto->messages->getHistory([
    /* Название канала, без @ */
    'peer' => '@channel', 
    'offset_id' => 0, 
    'offset_date' => 0, 
    'add_offset' => 0,
    'limit' => 999999,
    'max_id' => 999999999, 
    'min_id' => 0, 
]);
```

Но этот метод дает сообщения только по одному конкретному диалогу. Подскажите, как возможно получить всю историю? По аналогии с методом getUpdates в TelegramBotApi

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. Если кому понадобится. метод getDifference